# How should Open SSL options be set when using a Node.js TLS socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I'm constructing a new [tls.TLSSocket](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_new_tls_tlssocket_socket_options) from an existing instance of net.Socket but cannot find anywhere in the documention where Open SSL options listed in the [Crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_openssl_options) page should be passed.

Tried creating a secure context using `tls.createSecureContext` and passing options as a `secureOptions` property, but the options don't seem to have any effect.

```
var constants = require('constants');
var tlsContext = tls.createSecureContext({
    secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION
});

var tlsSocket = new tls.TLSSocket(client, {
    secureContext: tlsContext
});
```

The `secureOptions` property doesn't appear to be documented, but I gave it a shot after looking at the Node.js [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_tls_common.js#L41).